# Not able to bind data in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I need to bind data for the submission of the form which is in table's column. 
I am trying to bind data like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="domain in domainlist">
 <td name="domain" ng-model="domain.domain" >{{domain.domain}}</td>
 <td name="status" ng-model="domain.status" >{{domain.status}}</td>
 <td name="price" ng-model="domain.price" >{{domain.price}}</td>
 <td><button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addCart()">Add To cart</button></td>
</tr>
```

but the output is undefined.

Comment: Can you add the controller code where `domainlist` is populated?

Comment: ng-model is meant to be used on `<input>` not `<td>`.  Where do you see undefined?  I assume you just mean that the output is blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete de ng-model from the td, ng-model are only for elements i/o

**Controller**

```
 .controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.domainlist = [{domain: 'myDomain1', status: 1, price: 200},
                         {domain: 'myDomain2', status: 1, price: 250}];
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="domain in domainlist">
     <td name="domain">{{domain.domain}}</td>
     <td name="status">{{domain.status}}</td>
     <td name="price">{{domain.price}}</td>
     <td><button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addCart()">Add To cart</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, remove the ng-model and pass the domain as parameter in addCart method, see here [`Plunker`](https://plnkr.co/edit/PFzcE2va342P9dK8aVh5?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- `ng-model` work with `form elements` like `input`,`select`,`checkbox`,`radio`,`etc..`
- You can directly use angular expression `{}` to bind the data in the `<td>`,`<p>`,`<span>`,`etc..`

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.domainList = [{"domain": 'myDomain1', "status": 1, "price": 200},
                         {"domain": 'myDomain2', "status": 1, "price": 250}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in domainList">
     <td>{{item.domain}}</td>
     <td>{{item.status}}</td>
     <td>{{item.price}}</td>
     <td><button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addCart()">Add To cart</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>  
</div>
```